I can't work out how to use the mask modifier
I am trying to create a very simple model using a mesh plane and texture image taken from Google Earth. I used a paint program to 'erase' parts of the edges to be transparent (alpha channel) but when I use that as a material the transparent areas show and won't work as a scenery object in MSFS. Someone (at a MSFS forum) suggested I use the mask modifier to remove those areas but I cannot find out with youtube tutorials how to do that as they all seem to use vertex groups and there are none in my model.
The blender file would be too large too attach here due to the large .png image file but can be downloaded from  https://mega.nz/file/3ipV0DDA#QsBMqImKzPtadapXhv2OAuxIKMjCwyr_KL7ZbIVzGH8
Here is the image (it is a retangular image and the edges and transparent areas are not displayed.-


Difficult to work out precisely what you're trying to do, but if you simply want to remove the part of the plane which doesn't have the image on it, just use the Knife tool to mark round the edge of the image then go into Face mode and select and delete the surrounding faces. Incidentally your Blend file is only just over 12 Meg in size even with the image packed into it so could easily have been shared via https://blend-exchange.com/.

You say that "the transparent areas show", what do you mean by that? First thing plug the Alpha output of the Image Texture into the Alpha input of the Principled BSDF, then in the 3D view, in Texture Paint mode use the brush in Erase Alpha mode

Thanks John.  Oh the knife tool. That's a good tool to do what I want (ie remove the areas of the 'model' which are 'transparent' in the material texture image). It's been a while since I last used Blender and the knife tool slipped my mind.   And moonboots thanks also for your response. The transparent areas which show only show when the blend mode is set to opaque and when I set it to alpha blend it does not show however when I add a spot light (a feature for MSFS) the whole object is only lit (at 'night') if the blend mode is set to opaque. I have not tried your method.
